# How can I filter for a specific date on a CQL timestamp column?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE downtime(
    asset_code text,
    down_start timestamp,
    down_end timestamp,
    down_duration duration,
    down_type text,
    down_reason text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((asset_code, down_start), down_end)
);
```

I'd like to get downtime on a particular day, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM downtime \
  WHERE asset_code = 'CA-PU-03-LB' \
  AND todate(down_start) = '2022-12-11';
```

I got a syntax error:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:66 no viable alternative at input '(' (...where asset_code = 'CA-PU-03-LB' and [todate](...)
```

If function is not allowed on a partition key in where clause, how can I get data with "down_start" of a particular day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `TODATE()` function to filter for a specific date. You can simply specify the date as `'2022-12-11'` when applying a filter on a CQL `timestamp` column.

But the difference is that you cannot use the equality operator (`=`) because the CQL `timestamp` data type is [encoded as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#timestamps) (Jan 1, 1970 00:00 GMT) so you need to be precise when you're working with timestamps.

Let me illustrate using this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE tstamps (
    id int,
    tstamp timestamp,
    colour text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tstamp)
)
```

My table contains the following sample data:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM tstamps ;

 id | tstamp                          | colour
----+---------------------------------+--------
  1 | 2022-12-05 11:25:01.000000+0000 |    red
  1 | 2022-12-06 02:45:04.564000+0000 | yellow
  1 | 2022-12-06 11:06:48.119000+0000 | orange
  1 | 2022-12-06 19:02:52.192000+0000 |  green
  1 | 2022-12-07 01:48:07.870000+0000 |   blue
  1 | 2022-12-07 03:13:27.313000+0000 | indigo
```

The cqlshi client formats the `tstamp` column into a human-readable date in UTC. But really, the `tstamp` values are stored as integers:

```
cqlsh> SELECT tstamp, TOUNIXTIMESTAMP(tstamp) FROM tstamps ;

 tstamp                          | system.tounixtimestamp(tstamp)
---------------------------------+--------------------------------
 2022-12-05 11:25:01.000000+0000 |                  1670239501000
 2022-12-06 02:45:04.564000+0000 |                  1670294704564
 2022-12-06 11:06:48.119000+0000 |                  1670324808119
 2022-12-06 19:02:52.192000+0000 |                  1670353372192
 2022-12-07 01:48:07.870000+0000 |                  1670377687870
 2022-12-07 03:13:27.313000+0000 |                  1670382807313
```

To retrieve the rows for a specific date, you need to specify **the range of timestamps** which fall on a specific date. For example, the timestamps for 6 Dec 2022 UTC ranges from `1670284800000` (`2022-12-06 00:00:00.000 UTC`) to `1670371199999` (`2022-12-06 23:59:59.999 UTC`).

This means if we want to query for December 6, we need to filter using a range query:

```
SELECT * FROM tstamps \
  WHERE id = 1 \
  AND tstamp >= '2022-12-06' \
  AND tstamp < '2022-12-07';
```

and we get:

```
 id | tstamp                          | colour
----+---------------------------------+--------
  1 | 2022-12-06 02:45:04.564000+0000 | yellow
  1 | 2022-12-06 11:06:48.119000+0000 | orange
  1 | 2022-12-06 19:02:52.192000+0000 |  green
```

**WARNING** - In your case where the `timestamp` column is part of the partition key, performing a range query is dangerous because it results in a multi-partition query -- there are 86M possible values between `1670284800000` and `1670371199999`. For this reason, timestamps are not a good choice for partition keys. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the `cassandra` tag above and click on **Watch tag**.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation: clear and to the point. I just removed the timestamp from the partition key. clicked watch tag:)